# How to disable a TextView

Tags: android

Is there any command i can use in activity class that disables `TextViews` that are created in xml file? I want to put that in an if clause like:

```
 if (something == null) {
     TextView.dontCreate();
 } else {
     TextView.setText("Hello");
 }
```

Comment: You could use `setVisibility(View.GONE);`.

Comment: use TextView.focusable(false) TextView.focusableInTouchMode(false);

Comment: setVisibility(View.GONE); worked thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the reference I find two methods:invalidate() and setVisibility() .But it's an english preference so with a broken english I couldn't distinguish them exactly.Maybe, you could have a try.